# Android YouTubePlayerView shows black color tint on video

Tags: android, youtube, fullscreen, android-youtube-api, tint

I downloaded YouTubeAndroidPlayer example from the following URL:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Using the PlayerViewDemoActivity example.

Playing the video on normal screen shows a black tint over the video as shown in the image.(The tint is not because of the stop icon.)

[image]

**When we press fullscreen button it goes away.**

[image]

***What are the reason for the tint ?How to remove it even when the screen size is normal ?***

Answer (score 0):

I know what a lot of time has passed. But I have found to solution for the same problem. May be it will useful for someone.

You need set in theme for your YouTubePlayerActivity a value:

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

For example:
1. Manifest.xml:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.YoutubeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/YoutubeDialog"
            android:label="@string/activity_youtube"
            >
        </activity>
```

2. styles.xml:

   //< style name="YoutubeDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.MinWidth" >

   ```
       <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
       <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
       <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
       <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
   </style>
   ```

Hope it help you!